# Помогите понять работу функций (функция в качестве аргумента)

Tags: swift

Начал изучать Swift и функции и вот столкнулся с проблемой.
Подскажите как понять ниже приведенный код:

```
   func genWallet (walletLength: Int) -> [Int] {
    let typesOfBanknotes = [50, 100, 200, 500]
    var wallet: [Int] = []
    for _ in 1...walletLength {
        let randomIndex = Int( arc4random_uniform( UInt32( typesOfBanknotes.count - 1 ) ) )
        wallet.append(typesOfBanknotes[randomIndex])
    }
    return wallet
}

    func sumWallet( banknotFunction wallet: (Int) -> ([Int]) ) -> Int? {
        let myWalletArray = wallet( Int( arc4random_uniform(10) ) )
        var sum: Int = 0
        for oneBanknote in myWalletArray {
            sum += oneBanknote
        }
        return sum
    }

    sumWallet(banknotFunction: genWallet)
```

Почему работает sumWallet(banknotFunction: genWallet) ?

func genWallet (walletLength: Int) требует же параметр **walletLength** на входе, а я его не указываю!

Откуда в данной функции берется значение **walletLength**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно разобрать построчно:

```
sumWallet(banknotFunction: genWallet)
```

вызывает `sumWallet` с аргуменотом функцией `genWallet` типа `(Int) -> ([Int])`.
Идем далше в `sumWallet`

```
let myWalletArray = wallet( Int( arc4random_uniform(10) ) )
```

тут вызывается функция аргумент `wallet` с параметром `Int( arc4random_uniform(10) )`, а эта функция в вызове определена как `genWallet`, то происходит следующее параметр `Int( arc4random_uniform(10) )` передается в функцию `genWallet`. Дальше отрабатывает `genWallet` и результат записывается в `let myWalletArray`. Ну дальше думаю обьяснять не нужно...

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю swift, но несложно заметить, что sumWallet принимает функцию, а уже внутри к этой функции применяется аргумент, сгенерированный случайным образом с помощью arc4random_uniform. То есть в момент вызова sumWallet нужно знать только имя функции, а уже реальный аргумент передается внутри.

Comment: Но до arc4random_uniform есть for _ in 1...walletLength и опять вопрос откуда он берется?

Comment: @ПетровКирилл он генерится в первой строке внутри sumWallet.

Comment: тогда разберем строку: func sumWallet( banknotFunction wallet: (Int) -> ([Int]) ) -> Int?    banknotFunction - это функция genWallet. wallet - это return wallet из функции genWallet?    А (Int) - это let myWalletArray = wallet( Int( arc4random_uniform((10) ) ) ) ?

Comment: @ПетровКирилл banknotFunction - это метка аргумента ([Argument Label](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)). wallet - это функция genWallet.